# HashCode for a recursive linkedList

Tags: java, hashcode

I'm trying to write an hashCode for a class that is similar to a LinkedList but managed in a recursive way, I kinda write a method but I don't think it's the most precise way to write the hashcode in a recursive way.
Any suggestions?
Do you think that equals is correct?
Here's the code so you can understand how the class works:

```
package poo.recursion;

import poo.util.CollezioneOrdinata;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ListaRec <T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements CollezioneOrdinata<T> {
private static class List<E>{
    E info;
    List<E> next;    //because every node can be considered as a sub-list
}
private List<T> lista = null;

public int size(){
    return size(lista);
}

private int size(Lista<T> lista){
    if(lista == null)
        return 0;
    return 1+size(lista.next);
}

public boolean contains(T e){
    return contains(lista,e);
}

private boolean contains(Lista<T> lista,T e){
    if(lista == null)
        return false;
    if(lista.info.equals(e))
        return true;
    if(lista.info.compareTo(e) > 0)   //because the list is sorted
        return false;
    return contains(lista.next,e);
}

public T get(T e){
    return get(lista,e);
}

private T get(Lista<T> lista,T e){
    if(lista == null)
        return null;
    if(lista.info.equals(e))
        return lista.info;
    if(lista.info.compareTo(e) > 0)
        return null;
    return get(lista.next,e);
}

public void add(T e){
    lista = add(lista,e);
}

private Lista<T> add(Lista<T> lista,T e){
    if(lista == null){
        lista = new Lista<T>();
        lista.info = e;
        return lista;
    }
    if(lista.info.compareTo(e) >= 0){
        Lista<T> n = new Lista<>();
        n.info = e;
        n.next = lista;
        return n;
    }
    lista.next = add(lista.next,e);
    return lista;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (!(o instanceof ListaRec))
        return false;
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    ListaRec<T> l = (ListaRec<T>) o;
    int lSize = l.size();
    int thisSize = this.size();
    if (lSize != thisSize)
        return false;
    if (lSize != 0) {
        return equals(l.lista,this.lista);
    }
    return true;   //because it means that they are empty
}

private boolean equals(Lista<T> object,Lista<T> lista) {
    if(!object.info.equals(lista.info))
        return false;
    if(object.next == null)
        return true;
    return equals(object.next,lista.next);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return hashCode(lista);
}

private int hashCode(Lista<T> lis){
    final int PRIME = 43;
    if(lis.next == null)
        return 1;
    return PRIME * hashCode(lis.next) + lista.info.hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);
    sb.append('[');
    toString(lista,sb);
    if(sb.length() >1)
        sb.setLength(sb.length()-2);
    sb.append(']');
    return sb.toString();
}

private void toString(Lista<T> lista,StringBuilder sb){
    if(lista == null)
        return;
    sb.append(lista.info);
    sb.append(", ");
    toString(lista.next,sb);
}

public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new IteratoreListaRec();
}

private class IteratoreListaRec implements Iterator<T>{
    private Lista<T> cor = null, pre = null;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(cor == null)
            return lista != null;
        return lista.next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if(cor == null)
            cor = lista;
        else{
            pre = cor;
            cor = cor.next;
        }
        return cor.info;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if(pre == cor)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        if(lista == cor)
            lista = cor.next;
        else
            pre.next = cor.next;
        cor = pre;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ListaRec<Integer> l1 = new ListaRec<>();
    ListaRec<Integer> l2 = new ListaRec<>();
    l1.add(1);
    l1.add(2);
    l1.add(3);
    l2.add(2);
    l2.add(2);
    l2.add(3);
    System.out.print(l1.hashCode());
}
}
```

Comment: Your equals is only checking size, not elements themselves.

Comment: Hint: read about tdd, unit testing and junit. Try to think up test cases that you can execute to figure if your code is behaving as you expect it to.

Comment: actually if the size is the same it calls a recursive private version of equals, that is the core of the method.@GhostCat I don't understand how this would help me with hashcode ahahaha